# display html select (from PHP) via jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, sql

So I have a PHP backend that pulls some data from SQL,  let's just say its a list of user ID numbers.

I want to be able to display that list in an html select, via jquery, after a button click.

In an attempt to partially answer my own question, I assume that I could either have a jquery function perform an ajax request, grab the data from PHP/SQL, and then somehow spit out the select with jquery.  Or, I could perhaps do the SQL query via PHP right there on the page, and somehow have the jquery function grab the output from that and put it into a select.

How would you do it?

a fill-in-the-blanks code example follows:

idea 1:

```
function button_click() {


               $.ajax({
                url: "PHP_backend.php",  // this does the sql query and returns the results
                type: 'POST',
                data: 'returnquery',

                    success: function(result) {
                    //?????  put the result array or whatever into a submit, perhaps with a foreach or something similar..??

                    }
                }); // end ajax    

            }
```

Or idea 2:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT userIDnumbers FROM users",$db);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
/// throw these results into an array or similar, $userIDarray[]
/// maybe I could have this PHP create hidden html fields for each row, and insert its value, and then get that via jquery
}

function button_click() {
///  create the html select, displaying the values from the sql query
/// get values from hidden html fields?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are sure that the button will be clicked always or very most of time, idea2 is better becouse overhead of send/receive Ajax (trafic) and its delay (time) will be removed

Comment: Thanks.  With that in mind, what would be the best way to move the data from the php/sql query into jquery?  Short of doing the hidden html values, I don't know of another way to move data between the two (I'm a newbie).

Comment: @jeremy, `JSON` is the best way to move every data(2D or more-dimention array) like query result (table) into javascript via ajax. for more details and an example see [this](http://www.factsandpeople.com/facts-mainmenu-5/26-html-and-javascript/89-jquery-ajax-json-and-php)

Answer (score 0):

if the web page is "public" (not for an intranet, behind a vpn), I strongly advise to not use any sql in jquery. It's simplistic to call the php ajax response file with arbitrary sql (ie what I want), and even modify anything in the data or database.